# list indices must be integers, not str , when assigning query string to field in forms

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I am getting a variable from view and then modifying in function later like this

```
class labelModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = Labels_tool_
    fields = ['apn', 'owner_name', 'situs_addr_One', 'situs_addr_Two', 'mailing_addr_One', 'mailing_addr_Two']
    apn = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Field.objects.values_list('name', flat=True), empty_label="(Choose field)")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
  //getting layer_id from views
        layer_id = kwargs['layer_id']
        print         layer_id
        layer=Layer.objects.filter(id=int(str(layer_id))).first()
        x=Field.objects.filter(layer=layer)
         //On this step when modify queryset I get error
        self.fields['apn'].queryset= Field.objects.filter(layer=layer)
```

When I do this I get the error 'list indices must be integers, not str ' . So how can I modify my query set ? [image: Stacktrace of error]

```
model.py
    class Labels_tool_(models.Model):
     map_id_labels = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=False, max_length=255)
        apn = models.CharField(null=True, blank=False, max_length=255)
        owner_name = models.CharField(null=True, blank=False, max_length=255)
        situs_addr_One = models.CharField(null=True, blank=False, max_length=255)
        situs_addr_Two = models.CharField(null=True, blank=False, max_length=255)
        mailing_addr_One = models.CharField(null=True, blank=False, max_length=255)
        mailing_addr_Two = models.CharField(null=True, blank=False, max_length=255)
        layer_id_labels = models.IntegerField(null=True, max_length=255)

Model of Field
class Field(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        ('date', 'Date'),
        ('datetime', 'Date + Time'),
        ('number', 'Decimal'),
        ('url', 'Hyperlink'),
        ('integer', 'Integer'),
        ('string', 'Text Line'),
        ('text', 'Text Block')
    )

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'fields'
        ordering = ['map_order']

    layer = models.ForeignKey(Layer)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sql_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

EDIT : Error is in `self.fields['apn'].queryset= Field.objects.filter(layer=layer)`   . As I have fields like this  `fields = ['apn', 'owner_name', 'situs_addr_One', 'situs_addr_Two', 'mailing_addr_One', 'mailing_addr_Two']`  . That's why error of list appearing . So how can I fix that ?

Comment: Full error traceback please

Comment: @OferSadan traceback which I am getting in browser ?

Comment: You said you get an error, I want to see which lines of code were the cause... so whatever you're getting, edit your question and paste it

Comment: @ephemeral, Include `model` and `fields` inside a `class Meta`. See [`here`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform).

Comment: @OferSadan done .Error is in last line in code that I pasted

Comment: @nik_m I did both , Model and fields are assigned already

Comment: In your question, the `model` and `fields` are **not** inside a `class Meta`. If they are, update your question and edit that, please :)

Comment: The Layer and Field model too @ephemeral

Comment: @nik_m Now error is "'labelModelForm' object has no attribute 'fields'" after adding them in class meta

Comment: @Exprator posted . Layer model is just a field saving layerid

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your form somewhat like this,

```
class labelModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    apn = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Field.objects.values_list('name', flat=True), empty_label="(Choose field)")

    class Meta:
        model = Labels_tool_
        fields = ['apn', 'owner_name', 'situs_addr_One', 'situs_addr_Two', 'mailing_addr_One', 'mailing_addr_Two']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(labelModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        layer_id = kwargs['layer_id']
        self.fields['apn'].queryset= Field.objects.filter(layer__id=int(layer_id)).values_list('name', flat=True)
```